# Is it possible to clone one div to another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page called riskscore.cshtml and in there i have one dynamically created div-tag with some span-tags. i want to have the same div-tag with the same span-tags in it on my next page called overview.cshtml. I am trying to use jquery like this:

```
 function copydiv() {
    $('.headdiv').clone().appendTo('.topinfo');
}
```

But this won't work. Is there another way to do it? or do i use the wrong syntax?

Comment: What do you mean by _next page_? Are you trying to copy nodes from one document to another?

Comment: Are you using ASPNET MVC? You could move this html code to a partial view.

Comment: i submit a form on that page en redirects to another page in the same project.

Comment: yes i use mvc4. How does partialview work?

Comment: @Daniel Gustafsson - if you go to a new page(document) all javascript reloads, so you cannot accomplish this using javascript. You can clone and append elements as long as you don't reload the page.

Comment: Okey thanks! but is there a good way to do this?

Comment: You could grab the class and other important info from the document element and save it in local storage and then recompile from storage on the next document... http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/